# Searching multiple columns in SQL for value vs storing in one column

Tags: sql, database-design

I need to store lotto numbers in a SQL database. There are 8 separate numbers that make up the lotto number.

EX: 07-12-34-40-59-80-88-89

I first thought to store this data in a single row with columns named lotto1 - lotto8. This makes sense because lotto numbers are always displayed low to high, and users will need to see the stored lotto numbers. Writing a select statement would be trivial.

I also need to see how many of the lotto numbers are winners. To do this I need to search for each winning number in every single column.

EX: If the winning numbers were 01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08, I would need to check every column to see "07" is in my lotto1 column.

Checking for winners would be easier if all lotto numbers were stored in a 1 column, and they had a LottoTicketID to associate the 8 rows of data with 1 ticket. When checking for winners, I don't need to say which specific numbers/positions were matches, just how many matches there were.

SELECT LottoTicketID,Count(LottoTicketID) from LOTTOTABLE
WHERE LottoNumber in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08)
GROUP BY LottoTicketID

Storing this way would cause problems because I would need to write 7 joins just to display the numbers.

Can someone suggest a way to store this data so that I can:
1. Quickly displayed the lotto numbers/entires
2. Check for winners

Comment: Do the numbers have to be in a specific order to be considered a winning number?

Comment: @ZaneBien I believe Lotto doesn't care about order.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic It actually depends. In the US, we have the big money games where there are a few dozen numbers. In those, the order does not matter and each number can only be picked once. We also have smaller games like Pick3 or Pick4 where the numbers are 0-9 and the same number can be drawn multiple times. So your ticket might read 1-1-3-4, but if the numbers drawn were 2-3-1-4, you only matched 1 number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you'll probably want to tackle this is to have two tables to store information about lottery tickets:

- **lottery_tickets**: To store information about each individual lottery ticket:

  ```
  lottery_tickets
  ----------------------
  id [PK]
  first_name
  last_name
  date_given
  ...
  ```
- **lottery_ticket_numbers**: To store that corresponding lottery ticket's numbers:

  ```
  lottery_ticket_numbers
  ----------------------
  id        [PK](FK)
  number    [PK]
  position
  ```

Connect the two on the `id` field via a 1:N identifying relationship, and have each lottery ticket have 8 corresponding rows in the `lottery_ticket_numbers` table. The `position` field will keep track of each numbers' position (1-8) in the whole string of numbers.

What this will allow you to do is easily figure out the winning lottery tickets by JOINing the tables together and narrowing it down to which lottery tickets have *ALL* the matching numbers:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.number ORDER BY position SEPARATOR '-') AS lottery_number
FROM
    lottery_tickets a
INNER JOIN
    lottery_ticket_numbers b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
    b.number IN (07,12,34,40,59,80,88,89)
GROUP BY 
    a.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(b.number) = 8
```

The result set will look something like this:

```
id   |   first_name   |   last_name   |   date_given   |   lottery_number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
823  |   Zane         |   Bien        |   2012-01-01   |   34-80-07-89-12-40-59-88
2321 |   Jeff         |   Clark       |   2012-01-14   |   59-07-88-40-12-34-80-89
```

*Note*:

- If you are using MySQL, the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function consolidates the winning tickets' numbers in the format XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX with numbers in their original order that the person got it. If you're not using MySQL, I'm not sure if similar function exists in other DBMSs.

Now you'll probably want to store data about the actual winning lottery numbers as well. For this, you will *also* utilize two tables in much the same way: one for the lottery number and another for its corresponding numbers:

- **winning_numbers**:

  ```
  winning_numbers
  ----------------------
  id [PK]
  date_pulled
  ```
- **winning_numbers_numbers**:

  ```
  winning_numbers_numbers
  ----------------------
  id     [PK](FK)
  number [PK]
  ```

To query for the winning tickets:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.number ORDER BY position SEPARATOR '-') AS lottery_number
FROM
    lottery_tickets a
INNER JOIN
    lottery_ticket_numbers b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE
    b.number IN
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM winning_numbers_numbers
        WHERE id = <id of a particular lottery number>
    )
GROUP BY 
    a.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(b.number) = 8
```

Nearly the same as the previous query, except that now the number list is a result set from a subquery.

Displaying the winning lottery numbers is simple. Ex:

*Retrieve all winning numbers and their pull date; displaying their number string as numbers in ascending order, and ordering by the most recent pulled number:*

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.number ORDER BY b.number SEPARATOR '-') AS winning_number,
    a.date_pulled
FROM
    winning_numbers a
INNER JOIN
    winning_numbers_numbers b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY 
    a.id
ORDER BY
    a.date_pulled DESC
```

Note that when you insert winning numbers, you won't have to worry at all about the order of the numbers which you insert. Since they are always displayed in ascending order, the `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes care of that for you.

---

Now let's take a look at what you'll have to do if you use the column-based approach (storing winning numbers and ticket numbers as single row but with eight columns housing each number):

Assuming the schema:

`winning_numbers(id, date_pulled, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8)`

`ticket_numbers(id, fname, lname, date_given, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8)`

*Find all winning tickets for a given lottery number*:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM 
    ticket_numbers a
INNER JOIN
    winning_numbers b ON
        a.n1 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n2 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n3 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n4 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n5 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n6 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n7 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        a.n8 IN (b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8) AND
        b.id = <winning number id>
```

That's one heck of a lot of `IN`s if you were to ask me...!!!

The advantage of this approach is that you wouldn't need the MySQL-specific `GROUP_CONCAT` function to display the ticket numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> Storing this way would cause problems because I would need to write 7 joins just to display the numbers.

The only time you would need to do 7 joins to show all the numbers would be if you need them on a single row.  If you're processing these outside the database (or even using a stored procedure) collecting them into a readable format is trivial.

Another option that you might have, if your database supports it, would be to put all the numbers in a single array-typed column or use some sort of multi-row analytic function.  You could always just write a view on this to solve the problem once.

Comment: Nice! I think array would be a proper choice.

Comment: I was just about to suggest using a view for display. The array option is a good one too.

Comment: It was a while since I worked with arrays; can one index individual elements of the array? If no, then this would not be a good idea performance-wise, since OP needs to search on _all_ numbers in the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to write 7 joins for displaying the numbers? You could write something like this:

```
SELECT LottoNumber FROM LOTTOTABLE
WHERE LottoTicketID=n
ORDER BY LottoNumber
```

And you could check them using the query you suggested already:

```
SELECT LottoTicketID, Count(LottoTicketID) 
FROM LOTTOTABLE 
WHERE LottoNumber in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08) 
GROUP BY LottoTicketID
```

You could also restrict this list to just the winners by using:

```
HAVING Count(LottoTicketID) = 8
```

You could also store the lotto numbers as TINYINT to keep the database size down.

Comment: I believe the problem is that there are several winning **combinations**. So first of all you have several *LottoNumber* to check and there might be several such winning combinations.

Comment: That's ok, you can just check all the numbers and do an order by on the count:
`SELECT LottoTicketID, Count(LottoTicketID) 
FROM LOTTOTABLE 
WHERE LottoNumber in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08) 
GROUP BY LottoTicketID ORDER BY Count(LottoTicketID) DESC` 
Then you would get a list of tickets with at least one of the winning numbers, ordered by the number of found numbers descending ie. The people with 8 matches are found first, followed by those with 7 etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. All of the winning numbers are contained in the list: `(01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08)` which could just as easily be something more realistic like: `(12, 44, 55, 43, 22, 1, 32, 31)`. The `WHERE LottoNumber IN` statement, looks at all lotto numbers related to any ticket, and groups them by ticket number. Thus all possible winning combinations are returned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of advantages in storing the numbers in a single column, as you mention. IF the only remaining issue is the complexity of displaying them together, there are many possibilities for doing that cleanly and easily - and it's frequently overlooked, so the question is frequently asked.

It was dealt with well here, for several SQL flavors, as well as some platform independent options: 
[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: I was thinking that this should be tagged a duplicate of the above question, since the easiest/best answer is to use that structure, and query as described in that question and the answers.